# find and replace specific word in string

Tags: c#

I wish to write some c# code where I find a specific word in string and delete it from the string without deleting the whole string.

I tried this but it won't work :

```
if (openFile.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    // Read the files
    for (int i = 0; i < openFile.FileNames.Count(); i++ )
    {
        if (openFile.FileNames[i].Contains("Unknown Album"))
        {
            openFile.FileNames[i] = 
                openFile.FileNames[i].Replace("Unknown Album", string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and what do you mean "it wont work"?

Comment: What doesn't work? Please be specific.

Comment: What isn't working about that?  Does it error? Does it run and do nothing?  [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) to do to fix it?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that.  what error are you getting?

Comment: Not sure why everyone is downvoting. Obviously there is some confusion about the .FileNames property considering in the comments nobody picked up that it's readonly and a simple fix.

Comment: I don't think you should bother checking if the file name contains the string first... just replace straight away. Both `String.Contains` and `Sting.Replace` do an ordinal comparison on the input string for the specified term so you don't gain anything through checking first.

Comment: @Inisheer good catch, but the downvotes are probably because "it doesn't work" instead of "it doesn't compile" or "it throws an exception at this line which reads".

Answer (score 8):

The `.FileNames` property of the `OpenFileDialog` class is **readonly**. You will have to store the value in a temporary string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filenames.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
if (openFile.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    // Read the files
    for (int i = 0; i < openFile.FileNames.Count; i++ )
    {
        var file = openFile.FileNames[i];
        if (file.Contains("Unknown Album") && file  != "Unknown Album")
        {
            openFile.FileNames[i] = file.Replace("Unknown Album", string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if .FileNames[i] is readonly, this wont work either. It is in fact the same code as in the question. Replace always returns a reference to a new string.